# Extract html element attribute value with html agility pack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I need to retrieve a form anti forgery token from the html page.
To do so, I'm using the [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/), but I'm fairly new to it.

This is my code:

```
var page = new HtmlDocument();

page.LoadHtml(htmlPage);

var tokenNode = page.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/form/input").Attributes["value"].Value;
```

The 'tokenNode' variable is returning null.

I've managed to trackdown my problem to this method:

```
page.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/form/input");
```

If I simply use `page.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[3]);` it returns a value. However when I add the second `div` to my xpath, it starts returning null.

What am I missing here?

Edit: Got the xpath using chrome developer tools.

Edit2: After all the problem was in the Xpath I got from chrome.
TL;DR The html code in the brwoser was different from the one my http request retrieved, therefore the xpath was wrong.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826875/html-agility-pack-using-xpath-to-get-a-single-node-object-reference-not-set) a more thorough explanation

Answer (score 0):

To get anti forgery token from a page your could just call GetElementById method by passing id

For example

```
var page = new HtmlDocument();
page.LoadHtml(htmlPage);
string token = page.GetElementbyId("__RequestVerificationToken").GetAttributeValue("value", "");;
```

You no need to go through the nested path

Comment: I don't that will work. 

This is the html element:

`<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="otvY8PJ-xr7aJWYzI6K_Ls3xWHCSOevJEMQGN_rtVjvlsDG_3ySeBNDc9yT-G4JkpMpRqS2ZafrzkblJzByOIeKLv3FYsBBa4qI6mJ7jA_E1" />`

The "__RequestVerificationToken" isn't that element Id. 

Anyway, thanks for your help, I've figured my problem.